# SwiftUI. Access to properties from background

Tags: multithreading, swiftui

This problem is driving me crazy.
In principle the code below works correctly.
The authenticator that is called is a class defined in its own module (Authenticator.swift).
The code below is a method of the viewModel that conforms ObservableObject protocol.
The observed properties self.error and self.goToHomeView are properties published from the viewModel.
The authenticator method authenticates with FaceID. If authentication succeeds, error is nil, then the observed variable goToHomeView is set to true to switch to the Home view.
If error is not nil, then self.error is assigned which is of type LocalizedError and that triggers an alert in the view.
The problem is that an annoying warning appears all the time saying: "Publishing changes from background threads is not allowed; make sure to publish values from the main thread (via operators like receive(on:)) on model updates.”
I would like to know if anyone knows a technically valid way to modify values from the main thread from a secondary thread running in background.

```
Task {
  await authenticator.authenticate { error in
    if let error = error {
      self.error = error
    } else {
      self.goToHomeView = true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Surround your call with `Task { @MainActor in }` when you want to call back to the main actor.

Comment: The solution you propose is the right one. It works perfectly. Thank you.